# Continually Update State of List

Tags: elixir

Due to Immutability I'm having some trouble figuring out how to update a list of maps using Elixir. Here is my current failing attempt:

```
defp score_table_map(question, team) do
  prediction_score = Enum.find(team.prediction_scores, &(&1.question_id == question.id))
  construct_score_table(p_score)
end

defp construct_score_table(p_score) do
  information_map = []
  information_map = information_map ++ [%{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id}]
end
```

This `construct_score_table/1` function takes in up to 12 different `p_score`'s and I want to build a list of maps that looks like this:

```
[ 
  %{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id},
  %{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id},
  %{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id},
  %{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id},
]
```

But my current attempt builds it as separate lists altogether. How can I keep updating an existing list and append a map as an element each time?

Comment: Need more information to properly answer this question. First, you need to provide the structure of team and fix the error in your question. For example, the first function sets prediction_score and then user p_score?? It this sequenta code, or does the state need to live be persisted across multiple processes (i.e. web requests)?

Comment: Use [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#map/2) or [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#reduce/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to Immutability I'm having some trouble figuring out how to update
>   a list of maps using Elixir.

In functional languages, you pass data to functions, and the functions transform the data and return it.  So, the simplest way to do what you want is to pass the list of maps to your function along with the pscore.  Then the function can return a new list of maps.  Here's an example:

```
defmodule PScore do
  defstruct score: 0, team_id: 0
end

defmodule My do

  def update_pscores(list_of_maps, p_score) do
    [%{team_score: p_score.score, team_id: p_score.team_id} | list_of_maps]
  end

  def go do
    pscore = %PScore{score: 3, team_id: 1}
    pscores = update_pscores([], pscore)
    pscore = %PScore{score: 4, team_id: 2}
    pscores = update_pscores(pscores, pscore)
    IO.puts(inspect pscores)
  end

end

My.go
```

Compiling in iex:

```
> c "my.exs"       
warning: redefining module PScore (current version defined in memory)
  my.exs:1

warning: redefining module My (current version defined in memory)
  my.exs:5

[%{team_id: 2, team_score: 4}, %{team_id: 1, team_score: 3}] 
[My, PScore]
```

If you want to keep the pscore maps in the same order that they were added to the list, you can `Enum.reverse()` the list returned by `update_pscores()`.

You certainly don't need to create another process, e.g. an Agent or a GenServer, to update a list in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

Like you already mentioned, Elixir is a functional language meaning it has immutable data, so you need Processes to manage state. **There are a few ways you can do that:**

- Read/write data from an [`ETS`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html) Table
- Use a simple [`Agent`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/agent.html#agents)
- Or use a [`GenServer`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html)

---

**A simple example using an Agent would look like this:**

```ex
defmodule ScoreTable do
  use Agent

  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> [] end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def get_all_scores do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, &(&1))
  end

  def add_score(score) do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, &(&1 ++ [score]))
  end
end
```

Now just start your `ScoreTable` agent once the application starts, and you can read/write the state of the score list:

```ex
# Add a score
ScoreTable.add_score(team_score_map)

# Get all scores back
ScoreTable.get_all_scores
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `Agent` is a `GenServer`.